# Kendo UI Web - Grid Create/Update/Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, grid, kendo-ui

I'm having an issue with Kendo UI Web & DataSource. Read works fine, I've serialized the database objects in JSON and I'm able to view them in the grid. I need some pointers on how to get Create, Update & Delete working. I'm using the default MVC EF controller by the way.

Is there a complete guide to set the grid up? I've been looking but can't seem to find a suitable one.

Please note that I can't use helpers since I'm using Kendo UI Web (which does not include helpers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I changed the parameterMap function in the JS to the following and voila:

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
if (operation == "create") {
    return {
        Category: options.Category
    };
}
return options; }
```

Hope it helps anyone else out there who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this sample ASP.NET MVC project: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net-mvc/tree/master/grid-crud

Answer (score 0):

Update & Delete now work fine. I switched over to using Web API and found it much simpler. I followed the steps in [this](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-07-26/hello_kendo_ui_part_2_ndash_grid_crud.aspx) post. Only thing is, Create still won't work. Upon further inspection, I noticed the *id* field was always blank during creation.

I'm subscribing to the following POST event in Web API:

```
// POST api/Categories
    public HttpResponseMessage PostCategories(Categories categories)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Categories.Add(categories);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, categories);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = categories.CategoryId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?